# Plotting inequalities algorithm

Tags: algorithm, math, graph

I'm writing a simple graphing application using HTML5 canvas. The input is a system of inequalities like this (all functions are linear):

```
4x + y >= 4
x  + y <= 4
x,y >= 0
```

The output I desire is a set of points that form the shape to fill. For example, for this example the graph would be:

[image]
And the set of points: [0,4], [1,0], [4,0]. What is the algorithm to find these points? I know that the intersection point of lines is the solution of the linear system, but I can't figure out how to do the filling right. Please note, this question is not about the implementation of graphing system, but how to find the filled shape points.

Comment: Am I right that you whant to realise the algorithm like this: 1). Find the points of lines intersection. 2) Fill the area based on this information. Or you are looking for another solutions. Any way, it may be useful for you to take into account that for the line a*x+b*y=c the normal vector is (a,b)

Comment: Yes, this is exactly that I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me that your problem is really 2 problems: do the equations define a closed polygon, and how to fill it?

For instance,
* if your equations included x + y > 10, and x + y < 5, there is no way you'll find a solution to that, there is nothing to fill,
* if your equations were simply x > 0, y > 0, you would have a problem because the surface to paint would be unbounded / infinite.

Whether there is a solution to your system of equations is I believe roughly equivalent of the [simplex algorithm in Linear Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm): [Phase I of the algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm#Finding_an_initial_canonical_tableau) determines if the problem is feasible at all.

Whether that solution forms a closed polygon is not something typically of interest for Linear Programming. However, you could approach that by checking whether the 4 problems: Minimize x, Maximize x, Minimize y, Maximize y, given your inequations, have a solution. If any of these problems doesn't, then you know the problem is unbounded - which I think implies the polygon isn't closed.

Once you know the polygon is closed, I would simply compute the intersection points of all the lines, potentially reduce it to its [convex hull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull), and then fill the resulting polygon.

Comment: In fact, my application is the visualization of linear programming solution process using simplex method. x > 0, y > 0 always holds. For now I check every boundary point to see if it satisfies all inequalities, if so the point forms the filled shape. Yes, and this is much more complex for unbounded case.

Answer (score 2):

You can exploit the fact that any region defined as the union of linear half-spaces must be a single convex region, though possibly semi-infinite, which potentially adds messiness.

1. Begin by adding a rectangular "window" of inequalities that's a superset of the domain you're graphing. This way you can ignore cases where the result is a semi-infinite space.
2. Find the intersection points between all pairs of the boundaries.  This is two nested loops and an intersection checker.  (If desired, you can first find all intersection of the non-window inequalities, set the window to include all these, then add window-related intersections.)
3. Throw out all points that fail to satisfy any inequality.
4. If there are any points left, use a [convex hull algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) to find the enclosed region and draw it.

Note that if the graphing window is known in advance, you can make intersection calculation much more efficient by considering only the segments of boundaries lying inside the window and using an arrangement algorithm like enhanced Bentley-Ottman.

Answer (score 1):

I can propose the following algorithm. It is necessary to notice that this algorithm not based on the idea of finding lines intersection points and then somehow determine the area because this way seems to be complicated for algorithm realisation.
Since the space in computations is discret in any way, it seems natural to introduce some orthogonal grid.
So:

1. Lets introduce orthogonal grid with some characteristic cells size. This size depends on some details of your problem statement. Lets assume that the grid has N*M nodes (x_i, y_j), 0 <= i < N, 0 <=j < M
2. Lets find all points (x1_i, y1_j) which satisfy all K inequalities a_k*x1_i+b_k*y1_j-c_k <= 0 for 0 <= k< K. These points should be filled.
3. If the grid resolution is enough for visualisation thats all. If not we have to determine which line pass near the boundary points. For this we check each boundary point and its neighbors . If we find that Sth inequality is violated for the neighbor of the point it means that Sth line passes between this point and this neighbor.